# Azure Cache Preview cache getting reset

Tags: caching, azure

I have a default cache that is fairly small and static. It contains just string keys and a string objects.

Since I won't be using anywhere near the allowed amount of memory, I'd like to just preload all of the objects into the cache on startup and have them never expire. I added a log message on start indicating that the cache was loaded.

Right now the project is still in development so the cache isn't being hit often (other than by web spiders/crawlers/scripts). The problem I'm seeing is that every hour to few hours, I'm seeing the log message that my cache was loaded. I'd expect it to load once and then not reload until I force it to.

Is there any way to keep the cache "alive" so that it doesn't have to frequently reload? Is it like an IIS worker process that dies out after some amount of inactivity?

FYI I have the cache configured for Expiry Policy: Never, Time: 0min, Eviction: Disabled. Also the way I check if the cache is still alive is that on load I add a special object to the cache. Then I check to see if that object exists and if it doesn't I assume the cache needs to be reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who stumbles across this I ended up creating a scheduled task that hit the cache every 5 minutes. Since then, I haven't seemed to have any issues with it reloading. Not sure if this is the best answer, but it worked for me.

Comment: And a day later I ended up just stopping using it all together because I was having too many errors. I'll try again in a few months...